# Automatically associate shared library when installing application on websphere

Tags: websphere, shared-libraries, websphere-7

I use RSA and deploy using the server view. Everytime I clean or re-install my application, I need to run a python script that associates my application with a shared library. Is there any way to configure Websphere to do this automatically?

`Run this script when installing or deploying an application ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [installed optional packages](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/ccws_installoptpkg.html), the shared library can be automatically associated with the application when it is deployed.

Comment: This seems to work, but the description that IBM provides is really hard to get (for me). it seems possible to create a class loader on the server and associate the shared library with that class loader as well.

Comment: I'm sorry that topic was challenging to understand.  If you're willing, there's a Feedback link at the bottom of the page, and IBM does make an effort to improve the documentation.  Alternatively, if you list the problems here, I can try to direct the feedback to the right people.

Comment: I will use the feedback button :) The example was just hard for me to correlate to my application.